# Find all nonconstant polynomials P such that P({X})={P(X)}

Tags: polynomials, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find all nonconstant polynomials $P$ which satisfy $P(\{X\})=\{P(X)\}$, where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

I've tried to prove that the polynomial in question is linear, but I can't think of how to prove it, especially since we don't know anything about the constants

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide context for the problem? Questions that look like they want us to do homework for the asker tend to not be well received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$P(\{X\})$ is periodic with a period of $1$ (since $\{X+1\}=\{X\}$), hence $\{P(X)\}$ is also periodic only if $P(X)$ is linear, because for non-linear $P(X)$ (WLOG we assume $\lim_{x\to\infty} P(X)=\infty$), by defining
$$
I_k=\{x: k\le P(x)<k+1\}\quad,\quad k\in\Bbb Z
$$we have $$\lim_{k\to \infty}|I_k|=0$$which means that $\{P(X)\}$ cannot be periodic and the statement is proved $\blacksquare$